# Tfs with git: exclude path from PR build requirement

Tags: git, continuous-integration

I would like to relax the requirement of the PR build process, in order to not have the build to be mandatory when the changes are limited to specific paths.

The current configuration is to have a build run as part of the pull request and its successful completion being mandatory for the completion of the pull request and hence the code commit.

In concrete, I’d like to not have to run the CI builds for changes that are limited to the documentation folder, as the build in this case would provide little to no value.

Is this possible?

Comment: When downvoting, could you please add the reason why, so that the question can be improved?

Comment: The CI process kick a PR Build validation or a regular build?

Comment: The first. I’ve added the details in the question

Comment: You could have your CI system skip running in this case (or always exit successfully), but in order to do that, you'd need to mention what CI system you're using.

Comment: It's tfs with git. We use vNext builds with git versioned code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was added as a feature in newer versions of TFS (Since TFS 2018 I believe)